# How do I check for multiple Strings in an ArrayList at once?

Tags: java, arraylist, console, java.util.scanner

How would I insert 2 Strings into the same variable? One way I was thinking about doing this, was doing something like this:

```
static String devs = "Monter123","Epik_1";
```

That didn't work. So I decided to use ArrayLists:

```
ArrayList<String> devs = new ArrayList<String>(); // Is there a way to put this on one line?
    admins.add("Monter123");
    admins.add("Epik_1");
```

So.. I figured out how to input more than one String into an ArrayList. Now, I want to be able to use it. First I import:

```
import java.util.*;
```

to get all of the java.util.(Scanner, ArrayList, etc.) Then, I check if userInput is equal to ANY of the devs:

```
if(userInput.equals(devs.get(0))||userInput.equals(devs.get(1))){
  System.out.println("You are a dev");
}
```

As you can see in my code above, if I decide to recruit more devs, I would need to keep adding more lines of:

`|| userInput.equals(...`

into the if statement. This is very inconvenient. I am wondering if there is a:

`devs.get(all)`

type of thing.

**Refer to this if you have an answer:**

```
import java.util.*; 
class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> devs = new ArrayList<String>();
    devs.add("Monter123");
    devs.add("Epik_1");
    Scanner userINT = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
      String userInput = userINT.nextLine();
      if (userInput.equals(devs.get(0))){// I want this to check for devs.get(1) too, without the use of || userINT.equals(...!
        System.out.println("good");
      } else {
        System.out.println("bad?");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the documentation for `List` (which is extended by `ArrayList`). It has a `contains` method that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `List#contains`

The [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) interface offers the [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method. To quote the Javadoc:

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element.

Define your `List` object.

```
List< String > devs = List.of( "Monter123" , "Epik_1" ) ;
```

Ask the list if any of its items is a match for your user's input.

```
String userInput = …
boolean found = devs.contains( userInput ) ;
```

Example usage.

```java
List< String > devs = List.of( "Monter123" , "Epik_1" ) ;

String userInput1 = "Bob" ;
boolean found1 = devs.contains( userInput1 ) ;

String userInput2 = "Epik_1" ;
boolean found2 = devs.contains( userInput2 ) ;

System.out.println( userInput1 + " is dev: " + found1 ) ;
System.out.println( userInput2 + " is dev: " + found2 ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/1veWRp).

> Bob is dev: false
>
> Epik_1 is dev: true

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stream.anyMatch()` as shown in below example:

```
import java.util.*; 
class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> devs = new ArrayList<String>();
    devs.add("Monter123");
    devs.add("Epik_1");
    Scanner userINT = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
      String userInput = userINT.nextLine();
      if (devs.stream().anyMatch(s -> userInput.equals(s))){
        System.out.println("good");
      } else {
        System.out.println("bad?");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for each loop to search the same matching string for example:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Monter123");
list.add("Epik_1");

String userInput = scan.nextLine();
for (String string : list){
    System.out.println(string.equals(userInput) ? "Good" : "Bad");
}
```

If User enters Moniker1 then it checks your list and returns your output.